# How to change the colour of a custom UITableViewCell using an UIActionSheet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a TableView with multiple rows in it. Each row has different Custom UITableViewCell. I need to change the colour of this cell with the help of a UIActionSheet. That means when I select a row a Actionsheet should pop up asking to select a particular colour for the cell. Another important thing is that the cell should retain the colour even if the cell goes offscreen.

Here is my code. The problem with my code is that the cell is not getting updated real time. The colour of the cell get updates if I the row is selected again. Another issue is that if I scroll down the Cell colour changes to default white.

```
UIColor *cellColour;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    switch (indexPath.row)
       {
        case 0:
            [self displayActionSheet];
            cell.backgroundColor=cellColour;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void) displayActionSheet
{
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select row colour"   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Red",@"Green",nil];

    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;

    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];

    [popupQuery release];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
switch (buttonIndex)
    {
      case 0:
        NSLog(@"Red");
        cellColour=UIColor.redColor;
        break;
      case 1:
        NSLog(@"Green");
        cellColour=UIColor.greenColor;
        break;
      case 2:
        NSLog(@"Pressed Cancel");
        cellColour=nil;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }   
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Please edit your post to correct the code formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal, because `UIActionSheet` behavior is asynchonous.

When you call `displayActionSheet`, it displays the `UIActionSheet` on screen then continue the code (without waiting for the user to tap on a button of the action sheet). Then later when the user tap one of the action sheet's button, the delegate method `actionSheet: clickedButtonAtIndex:` is called.

What you need to do is:

- Use the `cellColor` property (I hope in reality it is a `@property` of your class and not a global variable like in the code in your question !!!) in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method (to set `cell.backgroundColor = cellColour;` here) so that the color is used each time the cell is reused and displayed onscreen
- Call `[tableView reloadData]` in your `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method to reload the tableView when the user has selected a color in your action sheet so that the cell color is updated.

Comment: I tried everything. No luck yet. Could you please provide some sample code?

Comment: Did you try using the `selectedBackgroundView` property to affect a brand new `UIView` with a fill color to the background? Or overriding the `setSelected:` method of your custom `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = alertViewCellColour;
        }
        
     if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = actionSheetCellColour;
        }
}  I have used above code to set the background colour Cell. It is working fine now. But not sure whether it is an optimised method.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I hope the code is fine for my requirement.

Comment: I would say that if it works, that's a good approach. The thing that the "selected" state of your cell probably mess with the background color you tried to set manually. You may try to call [`tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` too to be sure the standard selection system that modifies the background color does not mess with your own code modifying the background color too.